# Hadoop java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable

Tags: hadoop, networking

I´m executing this command in a 4 node hadoop cluster on the namenode node:

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

But it shows an error:

```
ls: Failed on local exception: java.net.SocketException: 
Network is unreachable; Host Details: local host is "namenode/172.16.1.2"; 
destination host is: "namenode":9000;
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://namenode:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

cat /etc/hosts:

```
172.16.1.2  namenode
172.16.1.3  datanode1
172.16.1.4  datanode2
172.16.1.5  datanode3
```

Comment: post a little more code

Comment: Hi. I didnt understand, more code? I just executed that command "hadoop fs -ls /" and get that error.

Comment: I update with configuration of two files..

Comment: Try using port `8020` instead of `9000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to `ping namenode` and see what happen. If ping reaches the host, check the firewall via `iptables` on your current machine and `namenode` because it is probably blocking related traffic.

Answer (score 0):

For me work setting JVM config

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true